# Click the mouse to continue python 2

Tags: python, mouseevent, mouse, rect

How can I continue the game when the player clicks on the mouse? I tried making a huge rectangle and then

```
if rectangleRect.collidepoint(mousex,mousey):

    blablablabla
```

I know for sure it can be done much easier, but I don't know how.
Anyone got some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should try:

```
if event.key == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:    #Remember to use from pygame.locals import *
    pass                            #Create code to make rectangle
                                    #Of course, top and bottom is mousex and mousey
elif event.key == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    pass                            #Do nothing else
```

Use a `while` loop and some `if` and `elif` staements to help continue the game as proceeded. You should make a class for the rectangle to make the creation easier and smoother. And to keep the rectangle from doing weird stuff, remember to use:

```
pygame.display.flip()
```